# Slow port scan?

Tags: security, android, ping, amazon

Probably no big deal although I have questions. Background: My home wireless was being overrun with all the devices. Have 6 people on the net and each have multiple devices. Then the kids would have friends over and the device count would go up. I have identified the mac addys for the local devices and modified iptables and dhcp to redirect unknown devices to a specific web page and not allow them on the network.

So for the problem. During my watching of the network I have found that Amazon, Xbox and some Androids ping multiple different ports on my router. Most ports are above 1024, although I have seen some below that. Pings happen about every minute and a half per device. Some ping 10 times, other less. Every once in awhile we get more than 10 pings; all are using different destination ports. Some pings are from the source out in inet land with most being from the local device. Sure, ping uses a tiny amount of bandwidth.

So my question: Anybody have any idea of what are these pings for? Looking at it as a security issue, it sure could be a 'slow' port scan to find holes in my systems. Since these devices are smart devices, just about anything could be done given a flaw in my network if there is one. I have dropped them at the router using the INPUT and FORWARD chains unless somebody gives me a good reason not to.

Maybe I am thinking all wrong about this - ideas?

Thanks
Todh

Welp, made an executive decision. Decided to drop all of the above packets and see who here complained. So far nobody! In other words, I gave up and just dropping stuff was easier.

Comment: What's the problem with the device count? I guess not all friends of your kids will use the network at the same time. What do you mean with "ping"? SYN packets? Please add more details to your question about your network and about the traffic you see. (protocol, port, source and destination address)

Comment: I guess that I don't have a problem with the device count, it just kinda overwhelmed me when I found out how many devices were connecting. Sure slows down the wifi when everybody is surfing. Ping/ping response - ICMP type 3 and type 8. Source is from the local amazon/xbox/android devices, destination is my router ( fedora  box ) for the most part, some go out to the internet to hosts that only resolve to in-addr.arpa names. The destination ports from what I have seen are from 900 - 65535 ... so far. I guess that I could allow type 3 and capture it for a bit if need be.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information instead of answering in comments. ICMP does not have port numbers. ICMP type 3 is "port unreachable", so this is probably the response to an attempt to open a TCP connection or to send a UDP datagram. Maybe some devices try to get direct connections through your firewall., see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking) . Without details about your traffic it is difficult to give an answer.